# Can't boot my PC

Tags: boot, bios

When I try to boot my desktop computer (Acer Aspire M3641), it sends me directly into a American Megatrends screen:

[image]

At the bottom you can see: "--MB OK, Single Channel Mode" with the -- being a number starting with 10 and going up 1 by 1 about every second. This occurred when I was installing SteamOS (Operating system based on Debian for gaming) and I used the "Shutdown" command in the built-in shell.

Before I always had a Acer screen with a white background and blue text, but now I can't even seem to get into the BIOS. After a period of time (about 40 minutes) it does boot but not into the bios, but into NVIDIA boot manager.([image: Boot manager] For the people wondering, yes I did try clicking the Del and/or F12 buttons. I'm not very experienced in this kind of stuff, so if anyone knows what I should do please tell me.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you're calling the NVIDIA boot manager?  It sounds like maybe you're either missing a video driver, or the current resolution setting isn't compatible with your monitor.  If you can't capture a screenshot, snap a picture with your cell phone and post a link to it on a sharing site like imgur.com.

Comment: @fixer1234 alright I will.

Comment: It looks like the initial hardware test is failing.  If you have access to another computer, try plugging the monitor in there using the same cable.  If you have access to another monitor, try plugging that in to your PC.  Identify the bad component (monitor, cable, or video output), by swapping until swapping one component identifies it as the culprit.

Comment: @fixer1234 I do have a laptop now, this is my old pc I wanted to fix so I could use it to game, it's hooked up to my television. Could that make a difference?

Comment: Do you have a monitor you can test it with to see if the TV is the problem?

Comment: @fixer1234 Question one: can I use my laptop monitor and attach it to my pc (sorry if it's a stupid idea, I'm not very experienced...) and 2: can the tv be the problem if I am able to perfectly watch Netflix and television through my setup box which is also attached via HDMI?

Comment: You can't use your laptop display as a monitor to test the PC.  Can you plug the TV into the laptop's video output?  Try connecting the TV to the set top box with the same cable that you're using for the PC.

Comment: @fixer1234 I actually own just one HDMI cable... yeah I kinda have to switch it around every time I want to use the other one. (Im about to leave so I might not answer immediately)

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you fixer1234 for all the support. I figured out the problem. I had "Fast Boot" disabled in the bios and I disabled it by pressing the "Del" button right after I heard a loud beep. I am now installing windows on it using s USB. Again thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad you got this figured out.  Consider posting your own answer.  That will help others who encounter the same problem.  You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, which will indicate that the problem is solved.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 first of all, how do I place my own answer (on Stack Exchange app) and second of all, how to indicate it as solved with the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While booting the PC, keep the button to open the BIOS within range so that after the loading screen you can immediately click it. After that, enable "Quick Boot" or "Fast Boot" or something similar. For the NVIDIA boot manager, it's just a built in thing, you can disable it by putting your Hard Disk higher up into the boot priority.

Comment: It occurred to me that your solution may just be hiding the problem.  The fast boot skips the full hardware check, so it doesn't display the error message.  But the error message indicates that there is a hardware problem.  Maybe it doesn't affect you and you're able to operate.  But still, you might want to pursue diagnosing this when you have time and access to the resources.

Comment: @fixer1234 after the full hardware check it does not show any error message, and the second menu, which saids: "Media test failure, check cable" is because my computer crashed during the installation of an operating system. I have installed windows now and the first 3 rows of the same screen still appear, and after that it boots.